# SQL Query to show all available rooms under a property

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL knowledge is not my strongest and I am struggling to find out how I can achieve what I am looking for.

When I run my query I want to show the name of the house and then underneath I would like to display all rooms which pertain to that house (these rooms can be rented)

Desired Display

```
15 Property Way - PP34PQ
   Double bedroom - £500.00P/M
   Single bedroom - £300.00P/M
```

Current Display

```
15 Property Way - PP34PQ Double bedroom - £500.00P/M
15 Property Way - PP34PQSingle bedroom - £300.00P/M
```

I am guessing I need to write some sort of grouping query to do this, but I am not quite sure of how I can achieve this.  My current query looks like this

```
SELECT properties.prop_details, properties.num_rooms, addresses.addr_line_1, 
   addresses.addr_postcode, addresses.addr_city, room_details
FROM rooms
JOIN properties ON properties.property_id = rooms.property_id
JOIN addresses ON addresses.addr_id = properties.prop_addr
JOIN cities ON addresses.addr_city = cities.city_id
WHERE rooms.property_id = 1;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to display this query?  Are you just using SQL?  Java and C++ have printf for example that can help you display things properly.

Comment: Im currently in SQL Developer just testing what is returned. I was wondering whether there was a way to display the results in the format described above, but if not then nevermind! :)

Comment: Envision your desired display as a spreadsheet, what title would you put above the second or third column? Because, the first row would receive another title than the second row it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you try to build a Report and try to do the display in SQL instead of your web solution.

Keep the data and its presentation separate.
Get your datatable, and then loop through it with PHP, creating a table for every building.

Ordinarely, you would use recursion, but MySQL doesn't support it.

You can use

```
ORDER BY premise.name, premise.id, room.nr, room.id
```

My guess is you need to group by room and property fields, using the max aggregate function for address and city fields, because a property (building) can have multiple addresses, one for each entrance...

```
SELECT 
     premises.field_1
    ,premises.field_2
    ,premises.field_3

    ,room.field_1
    ,room.field_2
    ,room.field_3

    ,max(address.field1) as adr_f1
    ,max(address.field2) as adr_f2
    ,max(address.field3) as adr_f3   
FROM Whatever

JOIN WHATEVER

WHERE (1=1) 
AND (whatever)

GROUP BY 

     premises.field_1
    ,premises.field_2
    ,premises.field_3

    ,room.field_1
    ,room.field_2
    ,room.field_3

HAVING (WHATEVER)

ORDER BY premises.field_x, room.field_y
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thankyou very much sir, sorry for the slow response, I've just moved into my new house!